# Swift Program Crashes on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to run a simple Table View app in swift with the iOS simulator. But the app crashes once the simulator starts.

**Here is my code**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deaden", "Home 1", "Teakha", "cafe Loisal","petite Oyster","For Kee Restaurant","pos Atelier","Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh's Chocolate"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return restaurantNames.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
            UITableViewCell {
            let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath:
            indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            // Configure the cell...
            cell.textLabel!.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
            return cell
    }
}
```

It says thread 1 breakpoint 1.5 in var restaurantNames.I have no idea where to start troubleshooting. Any help would be great.

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: It help if you add the **full* error message. Next up: readdup on using the Xcode debugger, the more you know about Xcode and the debugger the easier developing code wil be.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a crash, you just have a breakpoint there.

Go to Debug -> Deactivate Breakpoints

Here's some Apple Documentation on breakpoints

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html

Comment: Oh Cool! That fixed it for me. Thank you so much! Kind of feeling stupid at the moment :-D